# Toolbar not displaying title after adding enterAlwaysCollapsed scrollFlag

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I finally got a toolbar that fades away as I scroll down in my recyclerview and reappears when I scroll up but now the toolbar is not showing the title or navigation buttons. After testing out many things, I've discovered that when my toolbar has `enterAlwaysCollapsed` as an option in the `layout_scrollFlag` field, the title disappears but if I take it out the toolbar displays everything correctly but does not fade away on scroll. How can I keep the `enterAlwaysCollapsed` scrollFlag option AND keep my title/nav buttons?

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorGrey2"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed" // this is the problematic flag
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is how I've been trying to set the title to no avail:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallerie_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("TESTINGTITLE");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Comment: Could you try with just two of them: `"scroll|enterAlways"` and remove the `setTitle` from java side to test. Or, just use: `enterAlwaysCollapsed` to see what changes.: https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/appbarlayout-scroll-behavior-with-layout-scrollflags-2eec41b4366b